# How to decode ContentEncoding.SevenBit and ContentEncoding.EightBit MimePart with C# MailKit

Tags: c#, email, mailkit, decoder, content-encoding

I have this piece of code:

```
private string DecodeMimePart(MimePart mimePart)
{
    var decodedString = "";

    IMimeDecoder mimeDecoder = mimePart.ContentTransferEncoding switch
    {
        ContentEncoding.SevenBit => throw new NotImplementedException(),
        ContentEncoding.EightBit => throw new NotImplementedException(),
        ContentEncoding.Binary => new HexDecoder(),
        ContentEncoding.Base64 => new Base64Decoder(),
        ContentEncoding.QuotedPrintable => new QuotedPrintableDecoder(),
        ContentEncoding.UUEncode => new UUDecoder(),
        _ => throw new Exception($"ContentTransferEncoding '{mimePart.ContentTransferEncoding}' not supported"),
    };
        using var streamReader = new StreamReader(mimePart.Content.Stream, true);
        decodedString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        var encodedStringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(decodedString);
        var decodedStringBytes = new byte[4096];
        int decodedBytesNumber = mimeDecoder.Decode(encodedStringBytes, 0, encodedStringBytes.Length, decodedStringBytes);

        decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodedStringBytes, 0, decodedBytesNumber);

    return decodedString;
}
```

and I need to know what decoder I have to use with SevenBit and EightBit content-encoding. I've checked the documentation [here](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/N_MimeKit_Encodings.htm) but I didn't find the correct decoder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `mimePart.Content.DecodeTo()` instead of trying to manually do it yourself?

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks! 
I didn't check the documentation well and I didn't find this method